# Is it hard to make a online app, in the cloud, communicate with a cheap usb finger print scanner?

Tags: ruby

So, i came with a start up idea, but in order to make it happen, i need to make a web app communicate with any finger print usb scanner - those that you can buy anywere. It must take the scanned finger print and save it in the cloud data base.

It would be difficult,code wise?

I want to code it in Ruby on Rails

Comment: Would you hire me, then I will do that for you. :)

Comment: This is a question for another forum. See [Acceptable Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 3):

As RoR is **server-side** you would want to use some **client-side** language to interact with a *clients* usb, such as JavaScript. I know [Chrome offer a feature](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_hardware.html) to do this but am unsure if it will be available across multiple browsers.

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_hardware.html

Comment: so RoR for server side - since it communicates very well with data bases -, and JavaScript for the client side, for the finger print scanner communication?

Comment: have a look at the diagram: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Scheme_dynamic_page_en.svg

The local computer would run the client-side script (javascript) and the web server would run the server-side script (RoR).

Comment: thanks man. I will go with RoR + JavaScript